# How to get large parentheses with \tanh-function?

Tags: math-mode, braces

I want to show a function which includes the tanh of a fraction, i.e.
`\tanh(\frac{x - g}{h})`
but which gives me the normal small parentheses. I already tried `\tanh\(\frac{x - g}{h}\)` but this just omits the parentheses at all. So how can I get large parentheses which enclose the entire fraction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few examples:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\tanh\left(\frac{x - g}{h}\right)$

\[
\tanh\left(\frac{x - g}{h}\right)
\]

$\tanh\bigl(\frac{x - g}{h}\bigr)$

\[
\tanh\Bigl(\frac{x - g}{h}\Bigr)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\[ \tanh\left(\frac{x - g}{h}\right) \]

\end{document}
```